# Custom TextView XML Drawable with background property

Tags: android, xml, textview, drawable

I am using Horizontal `ListView` (list contains only a `TextView`) and now I would like to use an **xml drawable** to show `line` below the list item whatever `user taps`.

As we normally use in `Sliding Tabs`, check below **screenshot**, in this example user has selected **Tab1** ,and  **Tab2** & **Tab3** are in normal state.

[image]

In a same way I would like to implement my `custom drawable` to get same effect with my `TextView` and to get that, I am following [this](https://slothdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/05/19/underlining-views-custom-drawables-in-android/) link.

But still I did not get any success, see my TextView's property:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

**custom_textview.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ffff7a00" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="3dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#222222" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Which types of tabs you are using? design library or TabHost or TabLayout?

Comment: bro i am not using any tab ? read my question again

Comment: Ohh sorry I got it...

Comment: Try adding <item android:state_selected="false"> item,too in your selector xml.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your custom_textview.xml,with this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffff7a00" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#222222" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: but i am getting with each and every list item, whereas i just want to show with selected one, like :- Tab1 in above screen

Comment: Ok then, try to set property android:textIsSelectable="true" for TextView.

Comment: Try to set this property android:textIsSelectable="true" for TextView and in java when you select this TextView try to set  textView.setSelected(true);
Its working..

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using simple logic
create row.xml

```
<LinearLayoutadd attributes with orientation vertical>
<TextView/>
<View android:id="@+id/checkId/>
</LinearLayout/>
```

create a model(POJO)

```
public class MyModel{
String name;
boolean isChecked;
public MyModel(String name,boolean isChecked){
this.name=name;
this.isChecked = isChecked;
}
//apply getters and setters
}
```

now create you adapter
in your getView method 
check if the value isChecked is true or false if true set the background color of view whose id is checkId else change it to white

Now go to your OnItemClickListener
use for loop to make sure which item was clicked

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < youlist.size;i++){
yourlist.get(i).setIsChecked(false);
}
yourlist.get(positionoflistitem).setIsChecked(true);
youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

your done